# Centering and removing horizontal lines in tabular

Tags: tables

Edit: I have removed the two horizontal lines using `\cline(2-9)`

Below is the code I have used for my table and the result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
                      1,000 Group
                    & \multicolumn{2}{p{3cm}|} {\centering Cophenetic \\ Correlation}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{p{3cm}|} {\centering Global \\ Comparison}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{p{3cm}|} {\centering Baker's \\ Gamma} 
                    & \multicolumn{2}{p{3cm}} {\centering Fowlkes \\ -Mallows} \\
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{8}{p{15cm}} {\centering 10,000 Group} \\
    \hline
    & G1 & G2 & G1 & G2 & G1 & G2 & G1 & G2 \\
    \hline
    Group 1 & 1 & 2 \\
    Group 2 & 1 & 2 \\
    Group 3 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to change the following:

1. Remove the two horizontal lines below '1,000 Group' and centre the text vertically.
2. Centre  '10,000 group ' properly? So far I have just used a random number to centre it.
3. Make the cells G1 and G2 equally split between each main column.

Comment: Is there any reason, in the real document, for choosing  `p{3cm}`?

Comment: To center '10,000 group' you can use a `\multicolumn{8}{c}`

Comment: To make cells G1 and G2 equal you have to specify the widths of the main columns since you merge them afterwards for your headers. Do `{c|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}}` instead of `{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}` in your `tabular` options. It's a bit raw though

Comment: @Bernard I wanted to make the width length of all the columns the same

Comment: @BambOo works very well. How about vertically centering '1,000 Group' along the 4 rows?

Comment: @Ali: Does the new code yield what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Bernard's answer, with additional `booktabs` features

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell, booktabs}

\begin{document}

%\begin{center}
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{0.75\linewidth}{c|*{7}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}\toprule
                      10,000 Group
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c} {\makecell{Cophenetic \\ Correlation}}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c} {\makecell{Global \\ Comparison}}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Baker's \\ Gamma}}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Fowlkes \\ -Mallows}} \\ \midrule
    %\hline
    & \multicolumn{8}{c} {10,000 Group} \\ 

    & G1 & G2 & G1 & G2 & G1 & G2 & G1 & G2 \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-9}

    Group 1 & 1 & 2 \\
    Group 2 & 1 & 2 \\
    Group 3 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
%\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution with `tabularx` and `makecell`. However, you shouldn't use vertical and horizontal rules in general. You should take at look at package `booktabs` provides more professional-looking horizontal rules, with varying thickness and some vertical padding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx, makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{0.75\linewidth}{c|*{8}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}}
                      1,000 Group
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|} {\makecell[b]{Cophenetic \\ Correlation}}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|} {\makecell[b]{Global \\ Comparison}}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makecell[b]{Baker's \\ Gamma}}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makecell[b]{Fowlkes \\ -Mallows}} \\
    \cline{2-9}
    & \multicolumn{8}{c|} {10,000 Group} \\
    \cline{2-9}
    Group 1 & 1 & 2 \\
    Group 2 & 1 & 2 \\
    Group 3 \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I shouldn't have crossed out the 'remove two horizontal lines under '10,000 Group' in the question. I confused you guys. Apologies. What I meant to do was say I've managed to remove them. Your answer is good but if you can add `\cline(2-8)` to remove them and then centre 10,000 Group vertically along the 4 rows that would be of much help